# Save and copy a dynamically created html <input> box (not the .value of the box) from one DOM to another DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

When a user clicks a button, Javascript creates 2 html input boxes. I want to store these input boxes and copy them to another DOM (So the boxes will be on 2 different pages in one application, with one user click). 
I will use the localStorage object to work with the box values across pages. But any ideas on how I can move input boxes themselves across pages?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the <input>s? Just create new ones instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input1 = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input1);

var input2 = input1.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(input2);
```

```html
<body></body>
```